# What will be small signal trans resistance gain of shown circuit?

Tags: amplifier, bjt, feedback, negative-feedback, nodal-analysis

[image]

Take beta = 99.

I analysed this circuit using first considering this circuit as feedback circuit with shunt-shunt type of feedback and then  did the same analysis considering that the circuit is a common emitter amplifier ; i.e. I pretended that I don't know  feedback circuits and followed the basic approach of nodal analysis followed in small signal analysis.

I got different results for small signal Voltage gain from both type of analysis. Obviously, the analysis without considering the network as feed back is correct, but I want to ask that how to realize that I should solve using basic approach neglecting feedback concepts.

I am having vibe that it has to do something with approximations taken while feedback analysis that

[Y12]A<<[Y12]B

[Y21]A>>[Y21]B

are not appropriately satisfied in below circuit. That is why I got different answers. Please clear up this concept.
My calculations for Voltage gain
[image]

[image]

For calculating trans resistance gain
[image]

Why I am getting different answers for trans resistance gain using different approach?

Comment: The gain will be around \$A_V \approx gm*RC \approx 0.28S*510\Omega \approx 143 V/V\$

Comment: @G36 I am also getting the same answer by small signal analysis but after doing analysis considering circuit as an example of shunt-shunt feedback topology I get 74 as voltage gain.I am having problem in understanding that why there is so much difference in result.

Comment: Your, feedback analysis is wrong. Because Vin (ideal voltage source) will kill the feedback effect.

Comment: @G36 thanks for pointing out but I am also getting different answers when i calculate trans resistance  gain using two approach see edited